# How to write a time condition loop over a if-else

Tags: loops, shell

I have a if-else condition as follows:

```
if [[ "${DB_LOCK}" == "Done" ]]; then
    echo "DB image is ready, starting instances creation..."
else
    if [[ "${DB_LOCK}" == "FAILED" ]]; then
        echo "Failed to read db_lock.txt"
    else
        echo "DB image is not yet ready, trying again later..."
    fi
    exit 1
fi
```

After this loop, it actually run the `docker image prune -a --force` to cleanup all unused containers. But, sometimes it stuck in the above loop and never goes to this cleanup step.

Goal: give a explicit waiting period for the loop, using another loop after that period it should exit the loop with error and move to the next steps.

Comment: There is no loop in your code. If `$DB_LOCK` is not equal to `Done` or `FAILED`, the script exits, no further commands will be executed.

Comment: @dan exactly i wanted to avoid that. Even it fails, i wanted it to execute further steps or atleast the docker image prune. In the else statement i have this 'DB image is not yet ready, trying again later...' and there is no time limit for this.

Comment: Actually I read wrong, due to `exit 1`, the script _always_ exits if `$DB_LOCK` is not equal to `Done`. You can avoid that by simply removing `exit 1`.